# How do I remove glued-on carpet?

Tags: flooring, carpet, glue, removal

I'm trying to remove carpet from a small closet in our bathroom (at most 3.5 ft by 3.5 ft). I started to remove it and it looks to have been glued around the perimeter.  What's the easiest way to remove it? I recently bought a oscillating multi-tool so I'm wondering if that would work to loosen up the edges.

-M

---

UPDATE: I lucked out -- only part of the carpet was glued... the rest was actually nailed in and came up easy.

That being said, as a future homeowner, I'd like to hear suggestions for how to tackle this type of issue in the future.

Comment: What kind of surface is underneath and what do you plan on having there afterward?  (In other words, how destructive can we be? :)

Comment: @niall I'm planning to replace it with identical carpet. The subflooring beneath it is just standard plywood... nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, cut away the non-glued part with a craft knife or [carpet knife](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002N5V8).  Next, pull individual strands of the pile away from the mesh using a pliers.  Optionally, sand down the remaining bits of the carpet using your multi-tool.  Finally (and also optionally), patch any damage to the plywood subfloor with wood filler.

The last two steps are optional because it's in a small closet where nobody's going to notice any slight unevenness in the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I had some low pile carpet that was glued down to the subfloor in an addition of my house -- it was one of the first things I took out.  (although, I didn't get around to re-laying floor 'til some time after ... but the carpet was so nasty, it had to go, as it was near a not-quite secured door, and a bird managed to get in there and die)

I ended up cutting the carpet into managable strips (about 2-3 feet wide), then getting under it with something similar to a garden edger.  (but it had a flat blade, not curved ... [looks more like this 'scraper'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002N2GFV6))  I'm not sure what the tool was sold as ... I was storing my step-dad's gardening and other tools while he was stationed overseas.

It came up fairly easily, but there were globs of glue that I did some further scraping / belt sander / etc before laying new flooring (a bamboo floating floor)

Answer (score 0):

I scraped up sections of carpet with an ice scraper. I then poured small amounts of lacquer thinner on the wood floor and waited a few minutes for the glue to soften. I used the scraper to get it clean to the wood. Caution was used with flammability issues and fumes but it easily came up with this method.